# Geometry Quadrilateral Proof Question

Tags: geometry

For an arbitrary quadrilateral ABCD prove that Area(ABCD) ≤ (AB·CD+BC·AD)/2

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I've tried splitting it into triangles because of the divide by 2 at the end. Didn't seem to be getting anywhere with it though.

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot!